# Linksys Home Router resolves DNS with invalid DNS servers listed

Tags: router, dns

I am attempting to configure PiHole as an ad-blocker on my home network. I've configured my Linksys Nighthawk router to use its IP in the "DNS 1" setting under the Local Area Network, with 2/3 as all zeroes. After disconnecting the PiHole, I was surprised to see my devices were still resolving web sites, even after flushing the cache (ipconfig /flushdns). Wireshark shows DNS queries going to my router and receiving "answers", but the router shouldn't be able to reach the DNS server. I tried going websites I've never visited, and it resolves them. Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if you remove DNS 2 & 3 on the LAN interface?  Is the router able to ping the PiHole?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the 2ed and 3rd DNS opinions pi hole or 127.0.0.1.
I suspect that your ISP is seeing the port 53 and redirecting to their inhouse DNS

0.0.0.0 is a default route so it may crapping it to the router, which just is a forwarder more than an actual router to your ISP